# My java App Engine Managed VMs build doesn't deploy after 4/14/2015 update

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, managed-vm

My java App Engine Managed VMs build doesn't deploy any more using `gcloud preview app deploy target/myapp-SNAPSHOT` I get this:
`ERROR: Found no valid App Engine configuration files in directory`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage of `gcloud preview app deploy` changed in our gcloud 2015.04.14 release, you now have to specify the .yaml file for your module as well as `--project projectID`.  The documentation should be updated shortly.

For Java, we've released an updated maven plugin.  In your pom.xml, please add the following:

`<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.57.v20150425</version>
  <configuration>
    <gcloud_project>XXX</gcloud_project>
  </configuration>
</plugin>`

`mvn gcloud:deploy`

#### Update to a specific version of the SDK

You have some version of the SDK, but you want to change to a specific non-latest version, add the property:

$ `gcloud config set --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.55`

Then run:

$ `gcloud components update`

#### Returning to the current version of the SDK

$ `gcloud config unset --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version`

Then run:

$ `gcloud components update`

Comment: This release might be related to another issue [about managed VMs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698706/cannot-seem-to-install-google-cloud-managed-vms).

Comment: Can you please give an explicit example how our 'gcloud preview app' should look like from now on? 
You've also mentioned that we need to specify .yaml file for the module - what about Java apps? We should specify our xml file on the command line?

Comment: For Java, use the highest mvn plugin -- they've updated it since I posted the answer.

Comment: Using the java released SDK, you can now do appcfg.sh stage ... followed by a gcloud preview app run/deploy target/app.yaml  (stage will create the app.yaml from your xml.) -- This should get fixed next week.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Could you please tell the exact version that needs to be set for gcloud-maven-plugin?

Comment: I've moved to the the current version and things appear to work for me.  If you are still having issues -- let me know either way.  I'll fix / delete the question.

Comment: Note 0.9.58.v20150505 is the current released plugin.  I haven't yet tried the alpha one.