# Cannot seem to install Google Cloud Managed VMs

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, boot2docker, managed-vm

Following Google [instructions to install managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/sdk), everything seems to work smoothly until I get to this step:

```
 gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms
```

The result is the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app) Invalid choice: 'setup-managed-vms'.
```

I've made sure all the other dependent components are up to date.
The environment is:

- Windows 7 x64
- Google Cloud SDK 0.9.56
- boot2docker 1.4.1/1.5 (tried both)

Is there anything obvious I'm missing trying to get these managed VMs working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - that step is no longer required.  The docs should be fixed shortly.
You might wish to look at [My java App Engine Managed VMs build doesn't deploy after 4/14/2015 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664732/my-java-app-engine-managed-vms-build-doesnt-deploy-after-4-14-2015-update) for additional info.

Our images are now available on the public Google Container registry. For python, you can grab the image at gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat

It is important to note that you must do the following to use that image:

```
docker pull gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat
```

You can change the FROM line in your Dockerfile.  Also, it's important to note that this image does not have the GAE SDK included, but you can add most python libraries yourself.

Comment: https://gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat is not found on the server.  In addition, where would one go to get the Node.js runtime? Thanks.

Comment: @jmort253 For node, you can use [google/nodejs-runtime](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/nodejs-runtime/).