# Is there a mandatory requirement to switch app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Folks,
I'm using the recently released Google Cloud SDK 0.9.56 on Windows 7x64.
When trying to gcloud deploy my app using web.xml and appengine-web.xml, I get a response:

```
ERROR: Found no valid App Engine configuration files in directory
```

When trying to do the same with apps defined with app.yaml there were no issues.
Teammates with older SDK versions don't seem to have an issue.
Is there a mandatory requirement to use app.yaml in all apps?

P.S: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664732/my-java-app-engine-managed-vms-build-doesnt-deploy-after-4-14-2015-update) might be related but its actually a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry about this.

That question you linked is actually the same issue. You can use the new maven plugin described there to translate your appengine-web.xml to app.yaml automatically. We have a gradle plugin coming out very soon to do the same thing.

If you'd like to keep using gcloud directly without Maven or Gradle, you'll need to translate the appengine-web.xml to an app.yaml for now.

Let me know if I can help.